# infinite loop jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

Ill make this short. I've looked at a few topics here relating to this but no good. Here is the code; CSS, JS, HTML. I need and infinite loop and thought I had achieved one with the first JS script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 
 fadeLength = 2,
 fadeDelay = 6,
 fadeTime = fadeLength * 2000,
 delayTime = fadeDelay * 6000,
 totalTime = fadeTime delayTime,
 allElems,
 elemNoFade,
 i,
 fadingElem;
 
 for (i = 0, allElems = $('.toBeFaded').length, elemNoFade = allElems - 1; i < allElems; i = 1) {
  fadingElem = "#elem" + i;
  if (i === 0) {
   $(fadingElem).fadeIn(fadeTime).delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime);
  } else if (i === elemNoFade) {
   $(fadingElem).delay(totalTime * i).fadeIn(fadeTime);
  } else {
   $(fadingElem).delay(totalTime * i).fadeIn(fadeTime).delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime);
    }  
     };
});

//Thought the above would give me the infinite loop.

$(document).ready(function() { 
  
 $("#elem0").fadeIn(2000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
 $("#elem1").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
 $("#elem3").delay(12000).fadeIn(2000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
 $("#elem4").delay(18000).fadeIn(2000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
 $("#elem5").delay(24000).fadeIn(2000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
 });
```

```css
.toBeFaded {
  position:absolute;
  top:12%;
  left:30%;
  max-width:100%;
  height:640px;
  display:none;
}
.image-box {
  max-width:480px;
  height:640px;
  background:rgb(240,240,255);
  -webkit-box-shadow:12px -3px 12px #000,0 0 15px #666 inset;
  box-shadow:12px -3px 12px #000,0 0 15px #666 inset;
  margin:4.2% 0 0 29.3%;
  border:8px double #000;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Beta ttc1</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/styles/css/ttc-main.css">
<!--//SCRIPTS BEGIN\\-->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/javascript/pacs.fade.gal.js"></script> 
<script src="./assets/javascript/fadein.out.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
 
  <h1>Tamtam's Closet</h1>
   
    <div class="image-box">

   <img id="elem0" src="image170.jpg" class="toBeFaded" alt="">
    <img id="elem1" src="image176.jpg" class="toBeFaded" alt="">
        <img id="elem2" src="image175.jpg" class="toBeFaded" alt="">
         <img id="elem3" src="image172.jpg" class="toBeFaded" alt="">
          <img id="elem4" src="image173.jpg" class="toBeFaded" alt="">
           <img id="elem5" src="image174.jpg" class="toBeFaded" alt="">
         
       </div>



<h4><small><small><a href="https//tamtamsclosetcom1.ipage.com"></a>
</div>
 

 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not very experienced with javascript/jquery but it's something I feel really needs to be learned as I plan to be incorporating it into our store.
This thing works but only runs through once. Thank you in advance

Comment: Foots in my mouth. I said it worked. it did. I must have missed a tag or placement.  Well now. Would probably help if I would have included some images. I need bed! sorry folks

Comment: Extract this piece of code: allElems = $('.toBeFaded').length outside from loop.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Ill hurry up and close this so my girl doesn't see or it's, "I told you, if you got more sleep..." yada yada.. Thanks again!